# Is there a way to propagate the "nilness" of a variable in a chained call?

Tags: go

I have the following in Go:

```
checkItemState := action.Data.CheckItem.State
if checkItemState != "" {
            fmt.Printf("checklist item state: %s", action.Data.CheckItem.State)
}
```

Now if any of the items in the chain `action.Data.CheckItem` are nil/empty, I get a nil pointer dereference error, which makes sense.

But is there a language level way to get `checkItemState` if not nil, or `""` if any of the items in the chain are nil/empty.

(I come from Obj-C/Swift land where the nilness propagates)

Comment: No there is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can handle this nicely if you code some getters. Go method receivers are just regular function arguments, so it's totally ok to call something on a nil receiver:

```
type Foo struct {
    Name string
}

func (f *Foo) GetName() string {
    if f == nil {
        return "default name" // or "", whatever
    }
    return f.Name
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Q20lSo65Kx

This trick is used e.g. by Go protobuf implementation.

Comment: Thanks, this seems cumbersome though.